# Not detecting 2nd monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, amdgpu-pro

just recently switched over from Windows 10 -> Ubuntu 20.04.

However, the only issue I'm having (so far) is that my 2nd monitor is no longer being detected, whereas it worked fine prior to switching.

I installed the amdgpu-pro drivers as suggested by their website.

Both monitors are connected to my RX580 via HDMI.

`xrandr` output:

```
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.99*   50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any advice would be wonderful!!!